# win32com passing parameter as reference

Tags: python, win32com

I'm struggeling to get win32com.client working with Solidworks 2014.

Here is my minimum example:

```
import win32com.client
model_path = 'MW_011_500.SLDDRW'
ret_val1 = 0
ret_val2 = 0
sw_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('SLDWORKS.Application')
sw_app.OpenDoc6(model_path, 1, 1, "", ret_val1, ret_val2)
```

I'm trying to automatize Solidwork with the help of python. I managed to get the comclient running and the server is answering the command to open a document. BUT I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
     sw_app.OpenDoc6(model_path, 1, 1, "", ret_val1, ret_val2)
  File "<COMObject SLDWORKS.Application>", line 2, in OpenDoc6
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Typkonflikt.', None, 5)**
```

The API function I'm using is documented here:
http://help.solidworks.com/2012/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~opendoc6.html

They error I receive, tell's me it's the wrong type of parameter I'm using. On the fith place of the call.

But is there a way to use win32com with reference parameter? If so, how? Or can't it work? I couldn't find any solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe you're still interested- use OpenDoc to pass the path and the file type (http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~opendoc.html) or OpenDoc7 (for SW 2018 and later) and pass in only what you need with an open doc specification.

Otherwise you'd need to pass in variables by reference, which in my research Python doesn't allow.